# how to set button set text onclick data in text view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

This is simple question.. but i am not getting output. Description: in my activity i have  3 button A,B,C. in same activity i have 1 textview{textViewPatientType } also. When i onclick of button(A)  it must set text in textview(textViewPatientType)  as A. When i onclick of button(B)  it must set text in textview(textViewPatientType) as B.

my activity shows in this way

```
     -------------------------------------------------
     buton1-->onclick A|     textview(A)
     buton2            |
     buton3            |
     -------------------------------------------------
```

I try to do in this way but it acting as a toast.. when onclick (A) itcomes and  disappers.. 
So plz help me.. Thank u in Advance.

here is my code.

```
      button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
      button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    textViewPatientType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPatientType);

    buttonInPatient.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            try {   
                **textViewPatientType.setText("InPatient");**
  ServiceManager.callPatientService(WorkListView.this, "IP", user, pd);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(WorkListView.this, getResources().getString(R.string.inPatient), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: did you try putting this .settext("inpatient") outside this try, as it won't affect if its out of the try statement.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
TextView textViewPatientType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPatientType);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        textViewPatientType.settext("MyText");
    }
});
```

Comment: Boss i did same thing it act like a toast.. just when i onclick it appears and disapper.

Comment: then you might b doing smthng else is after doing this that is changing the text of the textview again so it comes once and than goes away.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the text of button as

```
ServiceManager.callPatientService(WorkListView.this, "IP", user, pd);
```

try to comment this line and see if the text remains the same ,, probably you are setting it again,else this looks ok

Comment: This act like toast Boss. just appear A when i onclick & it diappers.. i want permanent till i click button B.

Comment: thats what i m saying that you are overwriting it again somewhere else this works good,

Comment: as u told above i commented it.. it worked me fine.. when i enable above code it act like toast.. Above code ServiceManager is required for me.. in that i am passing data to listview etc.

Comment: Then probably you ServiceManager Class is doing something that changes it something else, you can find that else you can paste the code so that i can see

Answer (score 0):

replace your on click code with below code

```
public void onClick(View view) {


        try {   
            textViewPatientType.setText("InPatient");
  ServiceManager.callPatientService(WorkListView.this, "IP", user, pd);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```